# Allow assigning a score to tags to determine "interestingness"

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching, ignored-tags, tag-score

Let tags have a score of 0, interesting tags +10, ignored tags -10, by default. Just sum up the score and let the sign determine whether the question is interesting (>= +10), ignored (<= -10 ) or not marked special. But let the score be changeable, so that e.g. [retag-request -20] will make a [bug +10] tagged question still uninteresting.

As an addition, mark tags that have not been manually assigned scores to, to easily identify them. Bonus points for making the highlighting strength of interesting tags depend on the score, kind of like [Alconja's great greasemonkey script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49704/double-intensity-shading-for-questions-with-1-interesting-tags/49724#49724).

**edit** Concerning wildcards, please vote on the two @Grace comments to indicate your desired behaviour, or suggest another solution

Comment: I don't think this would do much good, at least not in the tags I frequent. Are there so many questions with overlapping tags? Aren't multiple tags often wrongly applied because the OP doesn't know where it fits in?

Comment: How would wildcard interesting tags be handled?

Comment: @Grace: good question... my first impulse would be: count the score for each occurrence only once in the sum, so e.g. [git* +10] would give a [git] [gitk] question still a score of +10 that could be compensated into ignoring when [sql -20] is involved.

Comment: @Grace: (cont.d) or counting each occurrence once, in which case the aforementioned² example would result in no highlighting or hiding. Maybe comment votes can decide on this.

Comment: ²) comments are not re-ordered, so in that case location-relative referring seems [ok](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62375/show-a-tooltip-warning-when-an-answers-states-above-or-below)...