# Don't show questions I asked with Ignored style

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, ignored-tags

I asked a question and gave it tags that appear in both my Favorite tag list and my Ignored tag list. I realize that styles for both types are being used, but visually the question looks more like an ignored question than a Favorite question. There is a [question addressing whether Favorite or Ignored should have precedence](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334/what-should-happen-with-a-question-that-has-both-ignored-and-interesting-tags), but it appears that Ignored is winning out. Therefore, my request is that questions I asked not be marked ignored even though I tagged them with a tag I am ignoring.

Update:
I am ignoring the tag because I am not as interested in questions with that tag.  I am including the tag in the question because it clarifies the scope of the question without requiring the content to be read.

I do not want to ignore the question because I asked it, therefore it is important to me.  I do not want it to be visually in the background.

Seems like the system could detect a match between the logged in user and the question and change the style accordingly.  If you know of a simpler way to provide the same benefit I am open to alternatives.

Comment: Um, how would this be a benefit? I don't understand. If you choose to ignore a tag, you want the system to ignore that request? Seems like a lot of extra work per-template for displaying not a lot of benefit ...

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49174/questions-ive-asked-should-be-optionally-highlighted-as-interesting-even-if-no

Answer (score 1):

I modified an existing Greasemonkey script to override the opacity change for questions with both Ignored and Favorite tags.  It doesn't meet my feature request as described, but does address the root cause of the request.

```
(function() {
    function GM_wait() {
        if (typeof unsafeWindow.jQuery == 'undefined') { 
            window.setTimeout(GM_wait,100); 
        } else { 
            $ = unsafeWindow.jQuery; letsJQuery(); 
        }
    }
    GM_wait();
    function letsJQuery() {
        $(function() {
            $("div.tagged-interesting").each(function() {
                $(this).css("opacity", "1.0");
            });
        });
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignored is ignored.  Not ignored is not ignored.  Never the twain shall meet.

Comment: So you will never ask a question containing any tags you are ignoring?  Just because you aren't interested in other peoples questions with the tag doesn't mean you want to ignore your own question.

Comment: I just don't ask questions.  Safer to just do as I'm told.