# What happens if a question is both tagged with favorite and ignored tag?

Tags: support, tags, ignored-tags, tag-watching

Suppose there is a question tagged both with Java (favorite tag) and Algorithm (ignored tag, don't show it option). What would be the SO behaviour? Would I still see the question (preferred way to go) or would it be hidden?
PS. I found this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334/what-should-happen-with-a-question-that-has-both-ignored-and-interesting-tags) but it doesn't answer mine - there are just people preferences.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both effects will be applied at the same time, which means you'll get a dimmed post with a different background color.

It's easy to test this yourself, by the way. I could verify this from your question by temporarily putting [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) in my favorite tags and [behavior](/questions/tagged/behavior) in my ignored tags.

Comment: Easy to test indeed, thanks for getting me out of the dark ;)

Answer (score 4):

This question came up over at [rpg.meta.se](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11206/62294), so the image below is taken from rpg.se.

#### Ignored tags set to be greyed out

In this image I have the four possible states in this order: Watched and Ignored, Ignored, Default, Watched:
[image]

A post with a watched tag and an ingored tag gets greyed out by ignore and gets the highlighting for watched.

#### Ignored tags set to be hidden

If you have ignored a tag and set to hide questions with that tag, then the question does not appear at all, even if it is also tagged with a tag you are watching.